# Property with default value not appearing in SDMPackageXML

Tags: powershell, sccm

I recently had to write a script to identify applications (in SCCM inventory) not properly configured, as per the standards. 
Deserialyzing SDMPackageXML, I found my way to the properties of interest (AutoInstall and RequiresLogon) but lost a lot of hairs until I found that a property set to the default value in SCCM, through the console, may not "appear" when checking SDMPackageXML.
Let me give you an example:

- application A is set to install whether or not a user is logged on

  `PS C:\> ([xml]($appA.SDMPackageXML)).AppMgmtDigest.DeploymentType.Installer
  Technology       : MSI
  ExecutionContext : System
  Contents         : Contents
  DetectAction     : DetectAction
  InstallAction    : InstallAction
  UninstallAction  : UninstallAction
  CustomData       : CustomData`
- application B is set to install only when a user is logged on

  `PS C:\> ([xml]($appB.SDMPackageXML)).AppMgmtDigest.DeploymentType.Installer
  Technology       : MSI
  ExecutionContext : System
  RequiresLogOn    : true
  Contents         : Contents
  DetectAction     : DetectAction
  InstallAction    : InstallAction
  UninstallAction  : UninstallAction
  CustomData       : CustomData`

Among 2000 applications, I have around 100 that are mistakenly configured to `RequiresLogOn    : true`, which I precisely had to identify.
At first, since I was testing my script only with applications such as application A, I could not find the value of the property. Then, after some testing, I understood that "whether or not a user is logged on" begin the default value, it may perhaps not appear in the details of my application. I changed it for an application and the property appeared when queried.

I think/assume that this example may concern each object within SCCM (2012, in my cas, not R2). The question is : without guessing, where can I find documentation about those default masks? How could I have known before guessing (since it took me some time)?

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the SDK documentation? AFAIK the only supported method for SCCM application mangement in powershell/c# is to use the `SccmSerializer`-class in SCCM 2012 SDK to deserialize the xml to an object of the `Application`-type.

Once you have an `Application`-object you should find all the documentation you need in the SDK.

Comment: Thanks, I did not even think about it, as my searches did not lead me there. I'll try it.